# MySQL InnoDB buffer pool size full as a christmas turkey

Tags: mysql, buffer, innodb

I use the power of SQL functions to make computation on some data by creating a Table that I manually remove after the job (I don't use temporary tables due to their limitations).

I have pushed the script since the a few days and my InnoDB buffer pool is actually completely full whereas usually the pool is used at 50%.

[image]

My question are : What the buffer store and keep in it when I create my little tables ? Is it a way to clear these things after the usage ?

Thanks guys !

Comment: I like the title of the question - although, it is not really a question. :)